# VBA - equation with unique numbers

Tags: vba, algorithm

Can you please help me to solve this problem ( Using VBA Excel )
We need to find the numbers X and Y such that:

1. 3*X = Y
2. X is a 4-digit number and Y is a 5-digit number
3. We find all the digits **(from 0 to 9)** in the equation.
4. digits must used **one time** in the equation

for example : 3 * 4321 = 567890

Comment: What have you tried? What is causing your code to not work?

Comment: Questions asking for help solving a puzzle aren't really [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) at stack overflow (this isn't a software algorithm - it's really a puzzle). You could try to ask for the algorithm on [StackExchange: Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/), then try to implement the algorithm and come back here if you need help debugging it :) good luck!

Comment: For a "brute" force" approach start by making a loop of all numbers between 10000 and 99999 which are exactly divisible by 3...    PS your example has a 6-digit Y

Comment: A faster brute force approach would be to loop from 4125 to 9876, then multiply by 3, and verify that all digits are present. I'm assuming that 3 is always in the equation, so the numbers can't use 3 as a digit.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facts we know:

- X must be in range 3334 <= X <= 9999
- Y must be in range 10000 <= Y <= 29997
- Y must be a multiple of 3

  - Thus, the sum of the digits of Y must be a multiple of three
  - In turn, since (1+2+4..9) mod 3 == 0, X must also be a multiple of three
- The least significant digit of neither number can be 0, i.e. neither can be a multiple of 10
- The least significant digit of the X cannot be 1
- The least significant digit of the Y cannot be 9
- Y must be a multiple of 9, so the sum of its digits must be divisible by 9

  - Thus, X must be congruent to 6 mod 9
  - In turn, Y must be congruent to 18 mod 27
- The most significant digit of Y must be either 1 or 2 (assuming no leading zeros allowed)
- There are 9 choose 4 == 126 ways to construct a 4-digit number, as well as a 5-digit number, without repeating digits (but not checking bounds).

With all of this in mind, your best bet is to probably brute force for Y, constructing numbers from combinations of 5 distinct digits, trying only numbers leading with 1|2 and performing a quick modulus check before checking if the equation itself is satisfied.

Comment: Hello Dillon Davis ! Thank you for the quick turn arnound. I've made it using this algo in my code it was very useful

Comment: @Aminoooox that's great to hear. If it fully answers you question, consider formally accepting the answer, so other's know that this question is resolved.